# JavaScript div height to match another div - 10px; Just a small math edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".content_R").css({'height':($(".content_L").height()+'px')});
        $("#content_R").height($("#content_L").height());
        var highestCol = Math.max($('#content_R').height(),$('#content_R').height());
        $('#content_R').height(highestCol);
        </script>
```

This code above will match the right divs height with the content div on the left. I am running into a bit of css and layout issues. I need to make it so that the right div is equal to the content div minus 10px.

Is there a simple edit to add to this code. I don't know javascript, only php and design.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it looks like a simple fix -

```
$("#content_R").height($("#content_L").height() - 10);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcuUz/)